# TextView text not wrapping on Android 4.3

Tags: android, textview, themes

I have a RelativeLayout containing a Textview. I want the TextView text to wrap on multiple lines.

It works fine on Android 4.1 and 4.2 (haven't tried earlier versions). However, on Android 4.3 the text doesnt wrap and is cut (see screenshots below).

Layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/feed_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/touchable_background_msf"
    android:padding="@dimen/feed_item_padding" >

    <com.binarymango.msfnews.images.RecyclingImageView
        android:id="@+id/feed_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_thumb_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_thumb_height"
        android:contentDescription="Description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/feed_item_icon"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/feed_item_icon"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/feed_item_icon"
        android:background="@color/text_background_msf"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:padding="@dimen/feed_item_text_padding"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/text_msf" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result on Android 4.2, the text is correctly wrapped in 3 lines:
[image]

But on Android 4.3, the text is just cut:
[image]

I've been trying to play with several attributes as mentioned elsewhere in StackOverflow in vain:

```
android:singleLine="false"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:width="0dip"
```

Also, I suspect it may have to do with the theme. My app uses Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: remove android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" and put different text size for different device

Comment: thanks but this doesnt work (no change in the result)

Comment: in which device or emulator you are testing ....

Comment: Testing 4.3 on Nexus 7 device and emulator, testing 4.2 on SGS2 and emulator

Comment: did you end up resolving this? i'm experiencing the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:line="3"` for example to have same behaviour as the first Image.

Comment: Did you try to also use a layout_width argument, and to set width to wrap_content ?